# jQuery $(window).load not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I ran into an something that did not expect today when removing part of a function that previously was loaded in my asset pipeline but needed to be extracted to a partial for some A/B testing.

I'm using the bigVideo.js library to load a full-screen video on the page. BigVideo.js started loading the wrong dimensions today when I extracted the code to the partial. The partial loads below the rest of my javascript assets.

I previously had the code incapsulated in a anonymous function inside my normal asset pipeline.

**original code (working)**

```
$(function () {
  (function () {
  var bgVid = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox: false})
  bgVid.show('http://videourl.com', { ambient : true });
  }();
});
```

Next, I tried to set this equal variable so I could call it in the partial. Video started loading without using correct dimensions.

```
$(function () {
  var initVid = function () {
  var bgVid = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox: false})
  bgVid.show('http://videourl.com', { ambient : true });
  };
```

in partial:

```
$(function () {
  initVid();
});
```

It looked like something was going on with the dom dimensions not fully loading, so I tried
switching the function to something like this:

in partial:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  var bgVid = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox: false});
  bgVid.show('http://videourl.com', { ambient : true });
});
```

Still no luck.

Finally, I resorted to using window.onload

```
window.onload = function () {
  var bgVid = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox: false})
  bgVid.show('http://videourl.com', { ambient : true });
};
```

It works?! So why is $(window).load failing here while window.onload seems to be working fine?

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).ready(function(){})` or `$(window).ready(function(){})`?

Comment: You didn't enclose it in `()` it should be `$(window).load(function(){});`

Comment: $(function () {}) is the same as $(document).ready(function(){}).

Comment: Inconsistent behavior. I navigate from one page to another and back but the ready or load functions were not hit. Actualy, in chrome developer tools the page I just navigated to was not loaded but I had the previous page for debug. Unexpected. The problem solved and I assume it was a bug.

Answer (score 17):

There are several different events you can use in order to be sure DOM is ready:

```
$(function(){ ... });
```

is the same as

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

and is executed when HTML document is loaded. From the other hand you can use

```
$(window).load(function() { ... });
```

which is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) equivalent of

```
$(window).on('load', function() { ... });
```

which happens later, when not only HTML document is loaded, but also all linked resources like images and styles as well. More about the differences you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready).

For modern browsers there is also an option to use `document.ondomcontentready` which is equivalent to non-standard `document.ready` added by `jQuery`.

As for me, I prefer not to mess with incompatibility of different browsers behavior and events support once I have tools like `jQuery` in my hand. Just use `$(function(){...})` and don't think twice.